# Understanding 外国でも使える電話を借りて来た

Tags: translation, particles, verbs

I'm having difficulty translating this particular sentence into English, and even thus understanding it fully.

> 私は成田空港で**外国でも**使えるけいたい電話を借りて**来た**から、問題がないよ。

My best attempt at a translation:

> I had a problem at Narita Airport because I had to rent a mobile phone to use.

I don't know how to translate the 外国でも bit and have it make sense nor am I sure about translating the 来た either.

Comment: Why did you translate 問題がない to "I had a problem"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me see if I can address these one at a time:

1. > 私は成田空港で　[ **外国でも使える　携帯電話** ]　を　借りてきたから、問題がないよ。

   The relative clause 外国でも使える is modifying 携帯電話, so 外国でも使える携帯電話 means "a cell phone that can be used even overseas".
2. > 私は成田空港で外国でも使える携帯電話を**借りてきた**から、問題がないよ。

   借りてきた means "borrowed", but since money was probably exchanged for the phone, I think "rented" is probably a better translation in this case.
3. > 私は成田空港で外国でも使える携帯電話を借りてきたから、**問題がない**よ。

   Did you notice the negative in 問題がない?  It means "had no problem", not "had a problem".

Here's my attempt at a loose translation:

> I rented a phone that works overseas at Narita Airport, so there's no problem.

Comment: I still don't understand the use of きた(来た) in the sentence and why its needed to mean 'borrowed' when 借りる means 'to borrow/rent' on its own? Everything else makes sense to me so thanks!

Comment: @Mononoke ～てきた is used both metaphorically and literally. In this case, it is used literally and 借りて来た means "I borrowed and came", i.e. "borrowed before I came", or here "I rented a phone at Narita Airport that works overseas (before I came here), so there's no problem."

Comment: I think that when ～てきた is used metaphorically, it is usually written in all 仮名, but when it is used literally (as in this case), it is usually written with 漢字.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Oh, then I suppose I misunderstood 〜てきた.  Maybe you could write an answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

You already have a great answer, but to clarify the points you asked about, 外国でも should be interpreted as

> 外国で + も

where 外国で使える means "able to use in a foreign country", i.e. "works abroad". も is "also", so that 外国でも使える means "also works abroad".

As I wrote in my comment, ～てきた is used both metaphorically and literally. In this case, it is used literally and 借りて来た means "I borrowed and came", i.e. "borrowed before I came", or here

> (Before I came,) I rented a mobile phone, which also works abroad, at Narita Airport, so there's no problem.

The English translation is a bit cumbersome, but such is the nature of literal translations.

*Edit*. A different translation (partly due to snailboat) could be

> I went and got a rental phone which also works abroad at Narita Airport, so there is no problem.

Comment: I see now, I totally missed that the で and も were separate particles and not together as in でも meaning 'but' or 'even if' etc.

Comment: But でも "but, even if" can also be understood as で + も...